# add number to multidimensional array python

Tags: python, arrays, addition

If I have a list like below:

```
t = [[221.0, 223.0, 43.4],[32.5, 56.7, 65.4, 54.6]]
```

How can I add a value to each number? For example, I want to add 1 to each number so the list would look like:

```
tt = [[222.0, 223.0, 44.4],[33.5, 57.7, 66.4, 55.6]]
```

Currently, I can write the code to replace the first list with the second list, but I would like to create a new list while keeping the first one as well. Thanks!

Comment: I am sure you might have heard of numpy arrays. In case not, and if you are not forced to use lists, you can convert your lists to array as `t = np.array([[221.0, 223.0, 43.4],[32.5, 56.7, 65.4, 54.6]])` and then say `tt = t + 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you're using lists, you can use the following nested list comprehension, which returns another nested list with `1` added to each number in the sublists:

```
[[j + 1 for j in i] for i in t]
[[222.0, 224.0, 44.4], [33.5, 57.7, 66.4, 55.6]]
```

---

So simply do:

```
t = [[221.0, 223.0, 43.4],[32.5, 56.7, 65.4, 54.6]]
tt = [[j + 1 for j in i] for i in t]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the partial function with the operator `add()`, which adds one to another number

```
from functools import partial
from operator import add

add_one = partial(add, 1)
print(add_one(1))
# 2
print(add_one(2))
# 3
```

and map the function `add_one()` to each element in the sublist.

```
t = [[221.0, 223.0, 43.4],[32.5, 56.7, 65.4, 54.6]]

tt = [list(map(add_one, i)) for i in t]
# [[222.0, 224.0, 44.4], [33.5, 57.7, 66.4, 55.6]]
```